# Block not able to load in the Controller

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, controllers

```
$this->loadLayout();
    $sidebar_blocks = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('catalog.compare.list');
    $sidebar_blocks->setTemplate('catalog/product/compare/list.phtml');
    $sidebar = $sidebar_blocks->toHtml();
    $sidebar = $this->renderLayout();
```

setTemplate on a nonObject error.

I am trying to load this block in the controller function.

Comment: are you sure the block with the name `catalog.compare.list` exists in your layout handles that you load?

Comment: catalog.compare.list exists in the catalog.xml under  <catalog_product_compare_index> handle

Comment: in order to work this code snippet, you need to make sure block with name `catalog.compare.list` should be defined in the layout for this controller

Comment: then the question is which controller that is using to do this  ?

Comment: i am using this block in the mycustom controller

Comment: ya that is the prblem. the block may be defined in `catalog_product_campare_index`. its not the point. That block should defined inside layout handle that is uniquely referencing to your custom controller

Comment: The block exists in `catalog_product_compare_index` but that layout handle is loaded only on the page `catalog/product_compare/index`.

Comment: oh ok i will add it to my custom handle.thanks all

Comment: Please add this as an answer and mark it as solution

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt : If you are mentioned me, then I posted it as an answer what I have commented here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have the custom controller like this.

```
class Namespace_Moduleneame_CustomController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function someAction()
    {
         $this->loadLayout();
         $sidebar_blocks = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('catalog.compare.list');
         $sidebar_blocks->setTemplate('catalog/product/compare/list.phtml');
         $sidebar = $sidebar_blocks->toHtml();
         $sidebar = $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

This means in `someAction()`, it is trying to set a template for a block that is already defined in your layout.

Suppose your route alias name is `custom` in `config.xml` file. Then  suppose you are requested your custom method like this `www.mysite.com/custom/custom/some`. Magento will eventually comes to your controller's `someAction()` to process it. First it will loads the layout. This means it will load all the blocks that comes under `custom_custom_some`. ie

```
File : `app\design\frontend\<package>\<theme>\layout\your_layout.xml`

<custom_custom_some>
     <reference name="content">
         <block type="catalog/product_compare_list" name="catalog.compare.list" template="catalog/product/compare/list.phtml"/>
     </reference>
</custom_custom_some>
```

If the unique layout handle holds this block, then `loadLayout()` will automatically load this block and `renderLayout()` then render that block. If this block do not defined there, then magento don't know which block that you are referencing in your controller and hence you cannot see output. ie in effect your `someAction()` should look like this.

```
public function
{
     $this->loadLayout();
     $this->renderLayout();
 }
```

Comment: thanks i am trying this solution and soon i will mark this as a solution