# Not able to load Block from Controller function

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, mage-xmlconnect

**I have extended the `cart.php` block and I render the block from my**

> `indexAction`.

In the `CartController` there are many other actions like `addAction`, `deleteAction` etc which calls the `indexAction` internally.

**PROBLEM** ::

When I create my own action, say `reorderAction` and call the `indexAction`, I am not able to get the block.
Strangely when I change my `deleteAction` or any other action to something else, then also the error happens.

I am not sure how the action and block mapping is happening in magento as I didn't see anything as such till now in the configuration.

I am sharing the important pieces of my code :

**CartController**

```
public function indexAction()
{
    try {
        $messages = array();
        $this->_getSession()->setCartWasUpdated(true);
        /* ERROR HAPPENS IN THE LINE BELOW */
        $this->loadLayout(false)->getLayout()->getBlock('xmlconnect.cart')->setMessages($messages);
        $this->renderLayout();
    } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
        $this->_message($e->getMessage(), self::MESSAGE_STATUS_ERROR);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->_message($this->__('Can\'t load cart.'), self::MESSAGE_STATUS_ERROR);
    }
}

//this action cannot load block when called (method newly created)
public function reorderAction()
{
    $this->indexAction();
}

//This action able to load block when called (method already there)
public function deleteAction()
{
    $id = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('item_id');
    $this->_getCart()->removeItem($id)->save();
    $grandTotal = Mage::helper('xmlconnect')->formatPriceForXml($this->_getCart()->getQuote()->getSubtotal());
    $this->indexAction();     
}
```

**CONFIG.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Dbaux_XmlConnect>
            <version>0.0.12</version>
        </Dbaux_XmlConnect>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <xmlconnect>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <dbaux_xmlconnect before="Mage_XmlConnect">Dbaux_XmlConnect</dbaux_xmlconnect>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </xmlconnect>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <dbaux_xmlconnect module="Dbaux_Xmlconnect">
                    <file>dbaux_xmlconnect.xml</file>
                </dbaux_xmlconnect>
            </updates>
        </layout>        
    </frontend>


<global>
    <blocks>
        <xmlconnect>
            <rewrite>
                <catalog_product>Dbaux_XmlConnect_Block_Catalog_Product</catalog_product>
                <cart>Dbaux_XmlConnect_Block_Cart</cart>
                <cart_totals>Dbaux_XmlConnect_Block_Cart_Totals</cart_totals>
                <checkout_order_review>Dbaux_XmlConnect_Block_Checkout_Order_Review</checkout_order_review>
                <checkout_order_review_info>Dbaux_XmlConnect_Block_Checkout_Order_Review_Info</checkout_order_review_info>
                <checkout_shipping_method_available>Dbaux_XmlConnect_Block_Checkout_Shipping_Method_Available</checkout_shipping_method_available>
                <customer_order_details>Dbaux_XmlConnect_Block_Customer_Order_Details</customer_order_details>
            </rewrite>
        </xmlconnect>
        <dbaux_xmlconnect>
          <class>Dbaux_XmlConnect_Block</class>
        </dbaux_xmlconnect>
    </blocks>
    <helpers>
        <xmlconnect>
            <rewrite>
                <data>Dbaux_XmlConnect_Helper_Data</data>
            </rewrite>
        </xmlconnect>
        <dbaux_xmlconnect>
          <class>Dbaux_XmlConnect_Helper</class>
        </dbaux_xmlconnect>
    </helpers>  
    <resources>
        <dbaux_xmlconnect_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Dbaux_XmlConnect</module>
                <class>Dbaux_XmlConnect_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
            </setup>
        </dbaux_xmlconnect_setup>
    </resources>

    <template>
        <email>
            <order_rating_email_template translate="label" module="dbaux_xmlconnect">
                <label>Order Rating Email Template</label>
                <file>order_rating_email.html</file>
                <type>html</type>
            </order_rating_email_template>
        </email>
    </template>

    <models>
        <dbaux_xmlconnect>
            <class>Dbaux_XmlConnect_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>dbaux_xmlconnect_resource</resourceModel>
        </dbaux_xmlconnect>
        <dbaux_xmlconnect_resource>
            <class>Dbaux_XmlConnect_Model_Resource</class>
            <deprecatedNode>dbaux_xmlconnect_mysql4</deprecatedNode>
            <entities>
                <revisions><table>xmlconnect_apprevisions</table></revisions>
                <installs><table>xmlconnect_appinstalls</table></installs>
                <banner><table>xmlconnect_appbanners</table></banner>
                <banner_store><table>xmlconnect_appbanners_store</table></banner_store>
                <promotionnotification><table>xmlconnect_appbanners_future_promotions</table></promotionnotification>
                <promotionnotificationuser><table>xmlconnect_appbanners_future_promotions_user</table></promotionnotificationuser>
            </entities>
        </dbaux_xmlconnect_resource>
    </models>  
</global>
```

I have removed unnecessary part from both the files. Please let me know if anything is needed.

**So, is there something missing from my end or any reason why this behavior?**

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the problem. It was something missing from my end.

That block should be defined inside the layout handle that is uniquely referencing to our controller.
A brief explanation is discussed [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/35198/block-not-able-to-load-in-the-controller).

Regarding my problem its resolved by adding the following lines in my `app/design/frontend/default/theme659/layout/dbaux_xmlconnect.xml`

```
 <xmlconnect_cart_reorder>
    <block type="xmlconnect/cart" name="xmlconnect.cart" output="toHtml">
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type><block>xmlconnect/checkout_cart_item_renderer</block><template></template></action>
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>virtual</type><block>xmlconnect/checkout_cart_item_renderer</block><template></template></action>
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>xmlconnect/checkout_cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template></template></action>
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>bundle</type><block>xmlconnect/checkout_cart_item_renderer_bundle</block><template></template></action>
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>xmlconnect/checkout_cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template></template></action>
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>giftcard</type><block>xmlconnect/checkout_cart_item_renderer_giftcard</block><template></template></action>
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>downloadable</type><block>xmlconnect/checkout_cart_item_renderer_downloadable</block><template></template></action>

        <block type="xmlconnect/cart_crosssell" name="xmlconnect.cart.crosssell" as="crosssell">
            <block type="xmlconnect/catalog_product_price" name="xmlconnect.catalog.product.price" as="product_price" output="">
                <action method="addRenderer"><type>bundle</type><renderer>xmlconnect/catalog_product_price_bundle</renderer></action>
                <action method="addRenderer"><type>giftcard</type><renderer>giftcard/catalog_product_price_giftcard</renderer></action>
            </block>
        </block>
    </block>
</xmlconnect_cart_reorder>
```

Please ignore the extra details.